# What communication do different C/C++ modules have with each other when compiled and linked?

Tags: c++, boost, g++

I have three main parts of a program I am writing, such as this:
    startwrapper.cpp
    deviceAcomms.cpp
    deviceBcomms.cpp

The application reads in data from one kind of device, and then serves up the data to another device using a different protocol (a management client).

startwrapper basically controls launching the application as a daemon, redirecting i/o to syslog, catching signals, etc. After it has set up the daemon environment it calls the StartServer method of deviceAcomms and passes in argv/argc.

My problem is that I am trying to see how the command line options are being stored and processed by the Boost program options library, but when I put in additional calls to syslog, nothing new is appearing in /var/log/messages.

So, does the second thread have access to the syslog calls, or is that something that also has to be passed to the next method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, second thread should be able to use `syslog`. By POSIX spec `syslog` should be thread-safe and so your problem is likely somewhere else.